# Big Data and a fwf files reading with filters

Tags: r, bigdata

I have searched at all possible areas and haven't been able to find the solution to my problem. I am hoping that someone here would be able to help me out. If you feel that this question is already answered, I would appreciate the link.

I am using `R3.2.2 64 bit` on a `windows 7` machine. I have a `fixed width file` of size `1.9 GB` and has approx `18 million` records in it. I need to read the file based on a filter condition `RecordID = "Cast"`. All my attempts to read the `file.dat` has failed due to memory constraints. Any help on how to use package `ff` for this purpose?

I am open to other methods also.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `LaF` package. See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716798/1427069

Once you create a `laf` object, you can create a data frame or data table using your row filter condition.

```
library(LaF)
laf <- laf_open_fwf("foo.dat",
                    column_widths = colWidths, 
                    column_types=rep("character", length(colWidths)),
                    column_names = colNames)
castData <- laf[RecordID == "Cast", ]
```

Comment: - Thanks. I was able to successfully create the object as an ASCII file. However, filtering the records, always lead to the below error  `comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types`.I have tried both index positions and `subset()` without much ado. I also tried `input <- subset(source_input, source_input$Record.ID =="Cast")`

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer. There are syntax examples elsewhere, but, for the sake of completeness, the syntax should be as follows:
`library(LaF)
laf <- laf_open_fwf("foo.dat",
                    column_widths = colWidths, 
                    column_types=rep("character", length(colWidths)),
                    column_names = colNames)
castData <- laf[laf$RecordID[] == "Cast", ]`